# Asterisk got hang CLI restart not work 12.8.1 on EC2 micro

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I have FIAF with asterisk 12.8.1 running on Amazon EC2 instance. I have created 20 extensions. I have created a JAVA AMI connection which is having 3 thread. Each thread have connection to asterisk AMI with Event: system, command and OFF. Randomly asterisk got hang and did not take any command from CLI. Only option have at that time is - kill the asterisk service and restart it. After that everything works fine.

```
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
```

I have attached the gdb when asterisk was hang by attaching process id and taken BT and BT FULL.

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x000000340d6df113 in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x000000000044eb7d in ast_el_read_char (editline=<value optimized out>, cp=0x7ffc71cdae0f "") at asterisk.c:2657
        num_read = 0
        lastpos = 0
        fds = {{fd = -1, events = 1, revents = 0}, {fd = 0, events = 1, revents = 0}}
        res = <value optimized out>
        max = <value optimized out>
        buf = " \255\315q\374\177\000\000H\255\315q\374\177\000\000\000`\357\023\231\177\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\364\226\317\033\000\000\000\000\n\237 \r4", '\000' <repeats 19 times>, "\005", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000`\357\023\231\177\000\000\005\000\000\000\064", '\000' <repeats 11 times>, "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000`\357\023\231\177\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000Xc\357\023\231\177\000\000Ь\315q\374\177\000\000\005\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\350\254\315q\374\177\000\000Xc\357\023\001\000\000\000\360\254\315q\374\177\000\000{=\240\017\064\000\000\000\b\255\315q\374\177\000\000\240\347\230\r\001\000\000\000\240\347\230\r4\000\000\000{9\240\017\064\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\247\347f\r4\000\000\000`\236\230\000\000\000\000\000}U\241\017\064\000\000\000`\236\230\000\000\000\000\000"...
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "ast_el_read_char"
#2  0x000000340fa1146b in el_gets () from /usr/lib64/libedit.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x000000000045199c in main (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>) at asterisk.c:4603
        title = "Asterisk Console on 'ip-172-31-51-113' (pid 9881)", '\000' <repeats 71 times>"\340, \024B\r4\000\000\000\000\300\315q\374\177\000\000\066\223 \r4\000\000\000\030\300\315q\374\177\000\000\060\300\315q\001\000\000\000\273\225\223\034\000\000\000\000P\222A\000\000\000\000\000\034\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\200\070\357\023\231\177\000\000.N=\366\000\000\000\000Фg\r4\000\000\000\tC\351\034\000\000\000\000\070\365\330\003\000\000\000\000.\000\000\000\000\000\000\000T:`\r4\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\005\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000"
        c = <value optimized out>
        filename = "/root/.asterisk_history", '\000' <repeats 56 times>
        hostname = "ip-172-31-51-113", '\000' <repeats 47 times>
        xarg = 0x0
        x = <value optimized out>
        f = <value optimized out>
        sigs = {__val = {134238211, 0 <repeats 15 times>}}
        num = 0
        isroot = 1
        rundir_exists = <value optimized out>
        buf = <value optimized out>
        runuser = 0x7ffc71cdae90 "asterisk"
        rungroup = 0x7ffc71cdae70 "asterisk"
        remotesock = <value optimized out>
        moduleresult = <value optimized out>
        l = {rlim_cur = 49317, rlim_max = 49317}
        __func__ = "main"
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "main"
(gdb)
```

I will appreciate if any body can suggest the reason or propose the work around for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have compile it with build_native=no

For change it, do

```
make menuconfig
```

before make command.

Please note, asterisk anyway will not work ok on micro instance due to not enought realtime cpu availible.

Also for non-expert it is recommended use already created AMI.

Comment: I have just compile it with build_native=Yes.

Comment: I have just compile it with build_native=Yes. I will update you the status after. I totally agree with you asterisk will not work ok on micro instance due to not enough realtime cpu available. But my question is what is the minimum EC2 instance for 50 sip extensions to work properly and stable. I am using EC2 micro just becose of free but once i got to know the 50 sip extension EC2 suitable instance, i will pay for it.

Comment: m1.small work ok upto 20-30 calls. c1.medium upto 80

Comment: arheops, sounds good. I am going to create c1.medium and will update you the status.